# Python: Error in function

Tags: python

So I have a function called LoopingSpace. It takes no parameter

```
def loopingSpace():
    for i in range (3):
        print ""
    i +=1
```

Whenever, it's called. It will print three blank lines. 
For example; if I type

```
def loopingSpace():
    for i in range (3):
        print ""
    i +=1

print"Hi"
loopingSpace()
print"Hi"
```

It will nicely output

```
Hi



Hi # As you can see three blanks.
```

However, when you put this function in a huge syntax like.

```
from random import randint

#Variabel 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
playername=[]
#Player disini mencatat skor. Jumlah Uang/Nilai Saham/Total harta/Health
playerOne=[0,0,0,0]
playerTwo=[0,0,0,0]
playerThree=[0,0,0,0]
#Stok disini mencatat banyak saham yang dimiliki peserta. A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H
stockOne=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
stockTwo=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
stockThree=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
#Tool disini mencatat apabila peserta memiliki barang. Diamond/Buy/Sell/Diamond/Poison
toolOne=[0,0,0,0,0]
toolTwo=[0,0,0,0,0]
toolThree=[0,0,0,0,0]
#Price disini mencatat harga saham. A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H
price=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] 
#clockTracker. Day dan turn counter
clockTracker=[0,0]
hari=["Senin","Selasa","Rabu","Kamis","Jumat","Sabtu","Minggu"]
listing=[playerOne,playerTwo,playerThree]
toolListing=[toolOne,toolTwo,toolThree]
#Nama saham
stockName=["Alama Inc.","Bwah! Bwah! Bwah! LCD","CUIT! CUIT CV","Dong Inc.","Eeeeeeeeeeeeah!","Foo il company.","Gogogogo Ind.","Halllo."

#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# THIS IS THE CODE. THIS IS THE CODE. THIS IS THE CODE
def loopingSpace(): 
    for i in range (3):
        print ""
    i +=1

#
def startingTheGame():
  loopingSpace()
    print "Selamat datang di Stock Game."
    print "Anda mau [M]ain atau Baca [A]turan?"
    answer= raw_input(">")
    answerRecognizerOne(answer)

#
def answerRecognizerOne(inbox):
    inbox.lower()
    if inbox=="a":
        ruleExplainer()
    elif inbox=="m":
        gameStarter()
    else:
        loopingSpace()
        print "Syntax tidak dimengerti. Mohon ulangi."
        loopingSpace()
        startingTheGame()

# 
def answerRecognizerTwo(inbox):
    inbox.lower()
    if inbox=="y":
        print "Kita akan mengambil kartu kesempatan lagi"
        cekKartuKesempatan()
    elif inbox=="n":
        print "Game akan dilanjutkan"


# 
def ruleExplainer():
    loopingSpace()
    print "Aturan:"
    print "Dalam awal giliran kamu, kamu akan mengambil kartu kesempatan."
    print "Kartu kesempatan kamu akan memberikan kamu hak untuk mengubah harga saham."
    print "Lalu kamu bisa jual atau beli saham."
    print "Kamu juga dapat bekerja pada Weekend, sehingga kamu dapat uang tambahan."
    print "Setelah 33 hari. Peserta dengan uang tertinggi akan menang."
    loopingSpace()
    startingTheGame()

# 
def gameSetUp():
    playerOne=[250,0,0]
    playerOne[2]=playerOne[0]+playerOne[1]
    playerTwo=[250,0,0]
    playerTwo[2]=playerTwo[0]+playerTwo[1]
    playerThree=[250,0,0]
    playerThree[2]=playerThree[0]+playerThree[1]
    price=[30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30]
    print playerOne
    print playerTwo
    print playerThree
    print price
    loopingSpace()
    print "Saya akan memberi kamu semua $250 untuk berinvestasi."
    print "Kamu juga akan memasuki dunia Wallsheet."
    print "Sebuah bursa saham di dunia Kryxban."
    print "Semoga beruntung."
    loopingSpace()
    answer= raw_input ("Tekan enter untuk melanjutkan")
    clockTracker=[1,0]
    print "Good Luck"
    loopingSpace()
    kartuKesempatan()

# 
def refreshScore():
    playerOne[1]=0
    for i in range(8):
        playerOne[1]+=(stockOne[i]*price[i])
    playerTwo [1]=0
    for i in range(8):
        playerTwo[1]+=(stockTwo[i]*price[i])
    playerThree [1]=0
    for i in range(8):
        playerThree[1]+=(stockThree[i]*price[i])
    playerOne[2] = playerOne[0] + playerOne[1]
    playerTwo[2] = playerTwo[0] + playerTwo[1]
    playerThree[2] = playerThree[0] + playerThree[1]

# Fungsi printScore -> Mengprint skor
def printScore():
    print playername[0]+": Uang: $"+str(playerOne[0])+" Saham: $"+str(playerOne[1])+" Total: $"+str(playerOne[2])
    print playername[1]+": Uang: $"+str(playerTwo[0])+" Saham: $"+str(playerTwo[1])+" Total: $"+str(playerTwo[2])
    print playername[2]+": Uang: $"+str(playerThree[0])+" Saham: $"+str(playerThree[1])+" Total: $"+str(playerThree[2])

# Fungsi kartuKesempatan -> Menjalankan fase Kartu Kesempatan
def kartuKesempatan ():
    refreshScore()
    print "Sekarang adalah giliran " + playername[clockTracker[1]]
    print ""
    printScore()
    loopingSpace()
    print "Kamu mengambil kartu kesempatan"
    answer = raw_input ("Kamu siap? Tekan enter jika kamu siap?")
    cekKartuKesempatan()

# 
def gameStarter():
    print loopingSpace()
    for i in range(3):
        answer= raw_input("Masukan nama pemain ke " + str(i+1)+ ">")
        playername.append(answer)
    gameSetUp()

# 
def cekKartuKesempatan():
    foo = randint(1,2)
        if foo==1:
            print "**KAMU MENDAPAT $25**"
            print "Dompet kamu tiba-tiba memberat."
            print "Kamu mengecek dompetmu."
            print "Ada $25 muncul!"
            (listing[clockTracker[1]][0])+=25
            updateScore()
            checkForToool()
        elif foo==2:
            print "**SAHAM NAIK 10%**"
            woo=0
            for i in range(8):
                woo= floor.(price[i]/10)
                if woo != 0:
                    price[i] += woo
                    print "Saham "+stockName[i]+" naik $"+woo
            checkForTool()

def checkForTool()
    if (toolListing[clockTracker[1]][0])!=0:
        print "Anda mempunyai 'Kesempatan Extra'. Mau dipakai? ( Anda punya "+str.(toolListing[clockTracker[1]][0])+" ) [y]es /[n]o"
        answer= raw_input(">")
        answerRecognizerTwo(answer)
```

It threw this error.

```
 File "main.py", line 31
    def loopingSpace(): 
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Note: I use online executor
Note: The online executor respectively use 2.7.4 and 2.7.5

**Where do I do wrong?**

**NOTE: When I delete the loopingSpace(): function from the code completely, it will then complain about the next function in line which in this case startingTheGame(), and so on**

**PS: This pyt is formed as a game. I will call one function (startingTheGame()) and this function will call other function and so on. I pretty sure you get the point.**

Sincerely,

DEO

Comment: You're missing the `]` at the end of the `stockName=` line.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error is actually on the line before it:

```
stockName=["Alama Inc.","Bwah! Bwah! Bwah! LCD","CUIT! CUIT CV",
           "Dong Inc.","Eeeeeeeeeeeeah!","Foo il company.",
           "Gogogogo Ind.","Halllo."
```

You have to add a closing bracket `]`:

```
stockName=["Alama Inc.","Bwah! Bwah! Bwah! LCD","CUIT! CUIT CV",
           "Dong Inc.","Eeeeeeeeeeeeah!","Foo il company.",
           "Gogogogo Ind.","Halllo."]
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your list is defined as:

> stockName=["Alama Inc.","Bwah! Bwah! Bwah! LCD","CUIT! CUIT CV","Dong Inc.","Eeeeeeeeeeeeah!","Foo il company.","Gogogogo Ind.","Halllo."

Notice how there is no `]` at the end of the list. Thus, you have technically not defined the list yet, and so python tries to continue making the list. It then reads the next line with text, which is `def loopingSpace():`. As the syntax `[..., "Halllo." def loopingSpace()` isn't proper syntax, a `SyntaxError` is raised at the line of definition.